# Add images to page with scroll on full screen page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an effect where I have a logo broken up into several images and want to use a scrolling effect to piece the logo together. The problem I am having is that the page is not a scrolling page. Using CSS grid, half the page is the logo (starting with the outline of the logo) and the other half is a `<h1>` that describes about the piece of the logo. Each piece of the logo has a separate `<h1>` with a different title and changes when the user scrolls.

How can I use a scrolling effect to give the page a slideshow like presentation while piecing the logo into completion?

Comment: It would help if you provided a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share mockup or screenshot that will be helpful. What I understood in your description, you don't need the grid.

You can make the logo part as `position: fixed`

And then when you are scrolling your h1 tags, you can easily add animation to your logo. For this you can use javascript like the following code;

```
$(function() { 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
      //do the first part merge
    } else if(scroll >= 1000) {
      //do the second part merge
    } else {
      //logo starting point
      }
  });
});
```

Also, for page scroll, I found a cool mini-library for you: https://github.com/CodyHouse/page-scroll-effects

*Crucial part is planning. You need to calculate when h1's finishing the scrolling and when their duplicate versions will start to merge with logo. You can also, make this process responsive and dynamic but it depends on your code. If you can share your code, we may help to convert it dynamic.

Comment: What if I need the h1 tags to fade in and out as well. The idea is the whole left half of the screen is the image that is being built and each piece has a quote that appears and disappears as the user scrolls on the right half of the screen. It also remains centered on the page as well. This is where I had trouble implementing this way.

Comment: Is it possible to draw a mockup? For h1's you can still make any effect you want, there is a need for sequential animation on certain scroll place. Maybe this one can also helpful; https://scrollmagic.io/, This library helps for creating scenes and sequential animation on certain scroll positions.